# Could I write these event listeners in a more efficient way?

Tags: javascript, loops, event-listener

Hi I have created 9 event listeners that are very similar and I would like to write them in a more efficient manner if possible. each button opens up the same hidden form and populates the dropdown menu with a different value.

```
const ordermulch = document.getElementById('Mulch');
ordermulch.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('order-form').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("input_9_11").selectedIndex = 1;
});
const orderptopsoil = document.getElementById('prem-topsoil');
orderptopsoil.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('order-form').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("input_9_11").selectedIndex = 2;
});
const orderstopsoil = document.getElementById('screened-topsoil');
orderstopsoil.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('order-form').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("input_9_11").selectedIndex = 3;
});
const ordercgravel = document.getElementById('crushed-gravel');
ordercgravel.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('order-form').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("input_9_11").selectedIndex = 4;
});
const orderpgravel = document.getElementById('pea-gravel');
orderpgravel.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('order-form').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("input_9_11").selectedIndex = 5;
});
const orderrrock = document.getElementById('river-rock');
orderrrock.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('order-form').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("input_9_11").selectedIndex = 6;
});
const orderhpbed = document.getElementById('bedding');
orderhpbed.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('order-form').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("input_9_11").selectedIndex = 7;
});
const ordersand = document.getElementById('sand');
ordersand.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('order-form').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("input_9_11").selectedIndex = 8;
});
const ordergseed = document.getElementById('grass-seed');
ordergseed.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('order-form').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("input_9_11").selectedIndex = 9;
});
```

Comment: What kind of elements are the ids (Mulch, prem-topsoil, screened-topsoil etc.) for?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is simple, use loops!

Collect all your IDs in an array:

```
const ids = ['Mulch', 'prem-topsoil', 'screened-topsoil']; // and so on...
```

Loop through this array:

```
ids.forEach((value, i) => {
    // todo
});
```

For each iteration you have to get the element first:

```
const element = document.getElementById(value);
```

And now you can add the EventListener to this element:

```
element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('order-form').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('input_9_11').selectedIndex = i+1;
});
```

All together:

```
const ids = ['Mulch', 'prem-topsoil', 'screened-topsoil']; // and so on...
ids.forEach((value, i) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(value);
    element.addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.getElementById('order-form').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('input_9_11').selectedIndex = i+1;
    });
});
```

Small side note: It's great that you're looking for optimizations and don't want to use redudant code. That's the only way to get better!

Answer (score -1):

`<select>` boxes come pre-built with this functionality without you having to manually set the `selectedindex` each time an item is selected. Instead of attaching the event to the click event of the individual selection items (stuff in the list), you can bind it to the `<select>` element's "change" listener and pull the `selectedindex` with much less code.

Example: assuming your html looks something like this...

```js
var products = document.getElementById('select');
products.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var index = products.selectedIndex;
  console.log("Index: " + index + ' - ' + e.target.options[index].getAttribute('id'));
  document.getElementById('input_9_11').value = e.target.options[index].getAttribute('id');
})
```

```html
<form id="order-form">
  <select id="select">
    <option id="mulch">Mulch</option>
    <option id="prem-topsoil">Premium Topsoil</option>
    <option id="screened-topsoil">Screened Topsoil</option>
    <option id="crushed-gravel">Crushed Gravel</option>
    <option id="pea-gravel">Pea Gravel</option>
    <option id="river-rock">River Rock</option>
    <option id="bedding">Bedding</option>
    <option id="sand">Sand</option>
    <option id="grass-seed">Grass Seed</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="input_9_11">
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0b8vz9fq/

Answer (score -2):

Make an array of all your IDs and then iterate it to add the event listeners:

```
const ids = ['Mulch', 'prem-topsoil', 'screened-topsoil']; // ...rest of IDs

ids.forEach((id, index) => {
    const elem = document.getElementById(id);

    elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.getElementById('order-form').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("input_9_11").selectedIndex = index + 1;
    });
})
```

You should also store `order-form` and `input_9_11` in a variable instead of finding them on every iteration.